# Which one is the best cordova plugin for firebase realtime database operation

Tags: firebase, cordova, firebase-realtime-database, html-framework-7

Working on IOT based project (final year project) & developing a highbird mobile app for that. I need to write and read database from my android app. For my app development currently I am using...

1. Node.js
2. Apache INT
3. Cordova CLI
4. Phonegap
5. Android Studio(for build)
6. Framework7(as a framework for app UI)

Currently using this cordova plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-realtime-database for firebase realtime database operation. This plugin is good,  but the features is limited. It only can write data into firebase realtime database, but can not read. This is the main limitation. I need to read realtime data into my app.

My question, is there any alternative cordova plugin is available which can read & write data from firebase realtime database? Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.